# Adobe Air: Create a Browse-Invoked-only app

Tags: browser, adobe, air, invoke

I have created an Adobe Air application that utilizes information received from a browser invocation using the BrowserInvokeEvent.BROWSER_INVOKE event. Without this information, the application can't run.

Unlike flashvars, because BrowserInvokeEvent.BROWSER_INVOKE is an event, the app must be given an addEventListener call.

Is it possible to also detect if the app was not invoked by the browser?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the docs, if you add event listener to WindowedApplication invoke event, you get all missed [BrowserInvokeEvents](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/BrowserInvokeEvent.html). If you get none BrowserInvokeEvents and only InvokeEvent, this must be non-browser run.